# MVC 4 read data from controller in a view using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I managed to post with ajax to a controller everything is good and I can see the data inside a controller. This is what I did:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: "./Enroll/saveTempSelectedPlan",
 content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: ({tempSelectedPlan: plan, tempSelectedTier: tier}),
 success: function() {alert("SUCCESS");}, 
   error: function() {alert("FAIL");}
});
```

and inside a controller this is how I read data:

```
public JsonResult saveTempSelectedPlan(string tempSelectedPlan, string tempSelectedTier)
{
    Session["TemporarySelectedPlanNumber"] = tempSelectedPlan;
    Session["TemporarySelectedTierNumber"] = tempSelectedTier;
    return Json("SUCCESS");
}
```

Now I am trying to post that data back out to a view, like this:

```
public JsonResult loadTempSelectedPlan()
{
    if (Session["TemporarySelectedPlanNumber"] != null && Session["TemporarySelectedTierNumber"] != null)
    {
        return Json(new { 
        tempSelectedPlan = this.HttpContext.Session["TemporarySelectedPlanNumber"].ToString(),
        tempSelectedTier = this.HttpContext.Session["TemporarySelectedTierNumber"].ToString()
    });
}

return Json("SUCCESS");
```

}

My question is how can I read that data back in the view do I create another post (would probably be GET). How do I read that data back in the view. Also if any improvements would be highly appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is the return value. Whatever you pass as an argument into `Json(arg)` will be serialized. The serialized arg is going to be in the JSON format.

Your success function will be injected with this as a parameter

```
success: function(data) {console.log(data);}, //now you can examine it
```

Also keep in mind that you can always inspect the response headers in your dev console of your browser. The returned json will be in there as well.